# Rails date to NSDate

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, date

I am trying to convert date from rails api to NSDate object.
The response date from api is `2014-11-05T16:29:09.614Z`
What does `.614Z` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The int before the `Z` are the milliseconds, the `Z` stand for Zulu which is the time zone:

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time:

> The UTC time zone is sometimes denoted by the letter Z—a reference to
>   the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which has been denoted by a Z
>   since about 1950. The letter also refers to the "zone description" of
>   zero hours, which has been used since 1920 (see time zone history).
>   Since the NATO phonetic alphabet and amateur radio word for Z is
>   "Zulu", UTC is sometimes known as Zulu time.

Thus you time format is:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

If you include the `Z` like in the example above the date will correctly converted to the devices current timezone.

Comment: Thank you. How can I get date components from this date (day, month, year)? NSObject description class method for this object is valid value (returns `2014-11-05 16:29:09 +0000`) but components returns 0.

Comment: Use the create `NSDateFormatter` to change the date string in a really `NSDate` then use [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/index.html) to get the specific date component you need.

Comment: I created NSDate category with:
`+ (NSDate*)dateFromApi:(NSString*)date {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    return [formatter dateFromString:date];
}` but components returns 0.

Comment: You might want to post a new question about this, but in general check whether the date return from you method is not `nil`.